# There is no data in Elastic APM using fleet

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack, elastic-apm, fleet

I used the below link to Install and configure Elastic APM
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/observability/8.7/ingest-traces.html

I have a linux ubuntu server, I Installed Elastic Search and Kibana and configured them, I can access kibana from outside of the server and there is no problem. but when I try to configure APM with fleet, there is no data in it.

Check APM server Status is successfull.
[image]

Check Agent Status is Successfull:
[image]

but there is not any data in APM:
[image]

Also using Postman I cannot acceess to port 8200 to get status of the apm-server
[image]

I need help with configuring APM on my server.
not: I use .net core ad apm agent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the Issue, the reason that I cannot see any data in apm integration was that I was adding an Integration inside a new Agent Policy (actually when you create an Integration it generates an Agent Policy and adds Integration inside that Agent Policy). image 1

[image]

To solve the Issue we need to click Existing Host tab and select Fleet server's policy to adding Integration.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the fleet server via `IP:port` but you can check the status of fleet server via `curl -f https://ip:port/api/status -k`

check the troubleshooting guide here.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/current/fleet-troubleshooting.html